# How to install FLTK project template in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, fltk

I downloaded FLTK 1.3.2 and the instructions for xcode 4 say that is enough to copy the FLTK folder (inside ide/Xcode4/Project Templates) into /Developer/Library/Xcode/Project/Templates/Other. So I did, but it seems like things have changed from xcode 4 to xcode 6: now all project templates have a directory that ends with .xctemplate, and inside the folder there is a single .plist file. Instead the FLTK folder has another hierarchy:

[image]

Indeed it doesn't work: the project template doesn't appear on the list when I select "new project" in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used FLTK, but I can tell you that Xcode custom project templates should go in the following location:

```
/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/GroupName
```

Where Username is your OS X username and GroupName is the group name on the left side of the New Project Assistant. You can create your own group name or use one of the built-in names, such as Other. You may need to manually create some of the directories in the path.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't find"? If you mean you can't find the path to the custom project template location on your Mac, reread the last sentence in my answer.